# How to create a upper-straight bottom border that is not affected by border radius

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to replicate the design of google calendar, and its text input box looks like this when clicked:
https://ibb.co/6Hqrnt4

but what I created looks like this:
https://ibb.co/HprQ125

My code was like

```
.element{
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

As you can see, the bottom border of mine gets whined up at the end.
The counterpart of google calendar isn't. I've noticed that the bottom border doesn't perfectly fit the original grey box(zoom in the image), but it doesn't really matter. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this by giving the blue border to a new element.

```css
.grey-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.blue-line {
   display: block;
   width: 100px;
   border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-box"></div>
<span class="blue-line"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here as I’m on mobile. Maybe the button is within a div with a bottom border and small border radius

```
<div class=“blue-line”>
    <a href=“#” class=“grey-back”>
<\div>
```